# Jquery chosen select

Tags: jquery, javascript

подскажите, если ли опция у этого плагина убрать выбор нескольких и выбирать только один пункт из выпадающего меню

```
http://clip2net.com/s/6Uxxq1
```

вариант версии, где с поиском чузен - не подходит. необходим именно мультиселект но без этого множественного выбора. спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы можно было выбрать только один пункт из списка, нужно установить параметр `max_selected_options.`

Пример:

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
    'max_selected_options': 1
});
```

Comment: все ок спасибо.